# Проблема с налогами Opencart 2.3

Tags: веб-программирование, opencart, модульность

Стоит задача сделать на версии 2.3 такое как на скриншоте. То есть налоговые ставки в соответствии с мультимагазином. В мыслях было привязать до групп покупателей, но так ничего и не вышло. Может кто знает готовый модуль для решения этой пробле[image: введите сюда описание изображения]мы?

Comment: Скрин того, чего нету в 2.3 и то что нужно чтобы было http://sec.dp.ua/123123.png

Answer (score 0):

На скрине у вас 1.5, в 2.х ищите:

`Настройка - Локализация - Налоги - Налоговые ставки`

Далее стандартно - синяя кнопка вверху справа добавляет новую ставку. В настройках ставки вы найдёте необходимый функционал.

Связка магазина и налога происходит через **Географические зоны**. Алгоритм следующий:

**1.** Создаём географическую зону. Для примера, создадим налог для харьковского филиала - `Харьков`:

```
система - локализация - географические зоны - добавить
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2.** Создаём одноимённый `Налоговый класс - Харьков`:

```
система - локализация - налоги - налоговый класс - добавить
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3.** Создаём новую налоговую ставку (или редактируем уже имеющуюся). Тут **важный момент** - опция `географическая зона` должна быть выставлена на на нашу геозону - `Харьков`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**4.** В настройках целевого магазина выставляем `Страна` и `Регион / Область`
те же, что и новой геозоне(которую как раз под этот магазин мы и создали)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В общем-то всё. Теперь при добавлении/редактировании товара под данным конкретным магазином, в селекте `Налог` будет доступен наш шовый налоговый класс `Харьков` с налоговой ставкой, которая будет просчитываться только для магазина в соответствующей геозоне.

Геозон, ровно как и налоговых классов, может быть любое количество, под любое число мультимагазинов.

Comment: Спасибо, но вот скрин того, чего нету в 2.3 и то что нужно чтобы было http://sec.dp.ua/123123.png